# Specify range for struts iterator when iterating over map

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator, ognl

Using struts iterator, we can iterate over a collection, list or map.

While iterating over a list, we can specify range using `begin` and `end` values as in :

```
<s:iterator value="list" begin="0" end="3">
...
</s:iterator>
```

I wanted to know if there is a similar way of specifying range when iterating over map. I tried:

```
<s:iterator value="map" begin ="0" end="3">
...
</s:iterator>
```

But this doesn't seems to work.

I want to know if there is way to do this, and the method of course.

Comment: Why not prepare the data on the Java side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<s:iterator value="map" status="stat">
 <s:if test="#stat.count <= 3">
   ...
 </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```